# How do I get the browser to display the image?

Tags: html, node.js

I want to display an image on a page in the browser but for some reason it will only display the alt tag (in addition to the ordered list below it). The path to the image is correct, it can be seen to the left in the screenshot above (I added the HTML code at the bottom). VSCode also suggests files while building the path in the img tag and it successfully finds the image 'test.jpg'.

[image: html code for page]

The screenshot below is what gets displayed. The rest of the project is written in JavaScript (specifically Node), but again the problem seems to be only with displaying the image.

[image: actual output on page]

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="images/test.jpg" alt="Grandma with a gun">
    <ol>
        <li><a href="first">first</a></li>
        <li><a href="second"">second</a></li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: added server code images below

[image: app.js]

[image: routes.js]

Comment: Show your `app.js`, only then we can see how you are serving it. Your HTML seems alright. Also, it says `blocked:other` in the network and you have got both AdBlock Plus and AdBlock turned on. Is it something to do with them?

Comment: @goto1 The OP hasn't given that info. Maybe they're doing it already, but that should work. I have asked the info in the first comment. Let's wait.

Comment: i guess your server/app does not server the files from the image folder, show your server code

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I tried disabling them but it didn't help

Comment: @AntonLoubman Use the [Express Static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually serving individual files, that's not the right way. For serving static files using Express, use the [Express Static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) server.

```
app.use(express.static('static'));
```

And move all the static files into a director named `static`. Else, what you might have to do is:

```
app.get("/test.html", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("./test.html");
});
app.get("/images/test.jpg", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("./images/test.jpg");
});
```

Comment: @AntonLoubman You're welcome. Always remember to read the docs! 